NestedScrollView and CupertionSliverRefreshControl flutter 3.19.4
I need to put pull-to-refresh with CupertinoSliverRefreshControl into NestedScrollView
Here is code example
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: NestedScrollView(
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) => [
          // Should work but isn't
          CupertinoSliverRefreshControl(),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.yellow,
              height: 300,
              child: Text('AppBar'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
        body: PageView.builder(
          itemCount: 2,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return CustomScrollView(slivers: [
              SliverMainAxisGroup(
                slivers: [
                  SliverAppBar(pinned: true, title: Text('SliverAppBar 1')),
                  SliverToBoxAdapter(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      height: 300,
                      child: Text('Some items'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SliverAppBar(pinned: true, title: Text('SliverAppBar 2')),
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  height: 10000,
                ),
              ),
            ]);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );

Help please
I need to use CustomScrollView inside of NestedScrollView body, but it isn't work
If there will be not scrollable widget everything is okey

If you are only using NestedScrollView just for refresh indicator then try using custom_refresh_indicator: ^3.1.0. It works for horizontal pageviews also.
